# Postfix: Duplicate addresses in alias_maps, does the order matter?

Tags: email, postfix

We have a Postfix server. There are multiple alias databases, as defined in the alias_maps parameter:

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/mail/aliases,hash:/data/mail/aliases,hash:/usr/local/mailman/data/aliases, nis:mail.aliases
```

Let's say that the string 'security' appears in /etc/mail/aliases and in /usr/local/mailman/data/aliases . 'security' is both an alias in /etc/mail/aliases (by default) and is a mailinglist in mailman.

What will Postfix do with email sent to 'security'? Will it consult /etc/mail/aliases before /usr/local/mailman/data/aliases? Does the order of the values in alias_maps matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postfix will check the maps in the specified order until it finds the first match and deliver the mail to that recipient.

Excerpt from [man 5 postconf](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html)

> **alias_maps (default: see "postconf -d" output)**
>
> > The alias databases that are used for local(8) delivery. See aliases(5) for syntax details. Specify zero or more "type:name" lookup tables, separated by whitespace or comma. **Tables will be searched in the specified order until a match is found.** Note: these lookups are recursive.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know where this is specified in the Postfix manual?

Comment: I don't know if this is explicitly stated anywhere in the documentation, but it's how Postfix handles these things. First match wins.